# Cause of Error: Error occured processing XML 'Premature end of file.'

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have that small red cross next to the Project Folder as a result of some kind of glitch. The  details in console is not very informative (see below).  The logs are not very helpful either (see below). I am working with SpringSource Tool Suite (STS).

The error (red cross) seems to go away if I create a new Project then copying the contents from the old project to new.  I have already did this several times, would like to find the root cause.

```
Description: Error occured processing XML 'Premature end of file.'. See Error Log for more details
On Element: servlet-context.xml
In folder: ProjectOne/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet

Error Log

1. Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core".

java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.data.internal.validation.InvalidParameterTypeRule.validate(InvalidParameterTypeRule.java:127)
        at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.data.internal.validation.InvalidParameterTypeRule.validate(InvalidParameterTypeRule.java:1)
        at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.model.validation.AbstractValidator$ValidationVisitor.visit(AbstractValidator.java:269)
        at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.model.AbstractModelElement.accept(AbstractModelElement.java:131)
        at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.model.validation.AbstractValidator.validate(AbstractValidator.java:142)
        at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.model.validation.AbstractValidator.validate(AbstractValidator.java:104)
        at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.internal.project.SpringProjectContributionManager$7.execute(SpringProjectContributionManager.java:260)
        at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.internal.project.SpringProjectContributionManager$9.run(SpringProjectContributionManager.java:291)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.internal.project.SpringProjectContributionManager.execute(SpringProjectContributionManager.java:294)
        at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.internal.project.SpringProjectContributionManager.runValidator(SpringProjectContributionManager.java:257)
        at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.internal.project.SpringProjectContributionManager.build(SpringProjectContributionManager.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:733)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:299)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:302)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:263)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:401)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:618)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2345)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:597)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:114)
        at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.core.SpringCoreUtils$1.run(SpringCoreUtils.java:793)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)    

2. Error creating Groovy language support
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.jdt.groovy.integration.internal.GroovyLanguageSupport cannot be found by org.eclipse.jdt.core_3.9.50.xx-201405030018-e43j8
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:340)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1212)
        at org.codehaus.jdt.groovy.integration.LanguageSupportFactory.tryInstantiate(LanguageSupportFactory.java:152)
        at org.codehaus.jdt.groovy.integration.LanguageSupportFactory.getLanguageSupport(LanguageSupportFactory.java:125)
        at org.codehaus.jdt.groovy.integration.LanguageSupportFactory.getParser(LanguageSupportFactory.java:54)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.initializeParser(Compiler.java:744)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.<init>(Compiler.java:298)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.<init>(Compiler.java:209)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.newCompiler(AbstractImageBuilder.java:562)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.<init>(AbstractImageBuilder.java:101)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.BatchImageBuilder.<init>(BatchImageBuilder.java:34)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.buildAll(JavaBuilder.java:254)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:174)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:733)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:299)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:302)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:263)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:401)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:618)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2345)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:597)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:114)
        at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.core.SpringCoreUtils$1.run(SpringCoreUtils.java:793)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
3. Unable to read variable and containers file
        java.io.EOFException
            at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
            at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager$VariablesAndContainersLoadHelper.loadInt(JavaModelManager.java:2789)
            at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager$VariablesAndContainersLoadHelper.loadVariables(JavaModelManager.java:2855)
            at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager$VariablesAndContainersLoadHelper.load(JavaModelManager.java:2658)
            at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.loadVariablesAndContainers(JavaModelManager.java:2480)
            at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.startup(JavaModelManager.java:4151)
            at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.JavaScriptCore.start(JavaScriptCore.java:4094)
            at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
            at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
            at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
            at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
            at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:478)
            at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
            at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:109)
            at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
            at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
            at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
            at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:464)
            at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
            at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
            at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
            at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:340)
            at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
            at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1212)
            at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
            at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
            at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
            at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
            at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.instantiateBuilder(BuildManager.java:906)
            at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.initializeBuilder(BuildManager.java:859)
            at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.getBuilder(BuildManager.java:545)
            at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.getBuilder(BuildManager.java:574)
            at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.getRule(BuildManager.java:1124)
            at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:612)
            at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2345)
            at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:597)
            at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:114)
            at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.core.SpringCoreUtils$1.run(SpringCoreUtils.java:793)
            at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
4. Unable to find Action Set: com.springsource.sts.roo.ui.actionSet
            An exception stack trace is not available.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as if the error means that an xml file called 'servlet-context.xml' in this location 'ProjectOne/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet' is malformed.

Discussion below however revealed that this error is very misleading in this case.

The real problem appears to be hinted at by the 'EOF' exception trace in the error log. Looking at source code around that stacktrace reveals a file 'variablesAndContainers.dat' somewhere in the workspace metadata probably got corrupted.

Rather than try to 'repair' the workspace it is probably the safest and easiest to create a new workspace and copy or import your project(s) into this clean new workspace.

Comment: Could be. But can you say why you think so? Or do you want me to guess? It's hard to help without more information.

Comment: Okay... to make sure it isn't what it appears to be (XML syntax error in said file), take the contents of your file and paste it into an xml validator. for example here: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp

Comment: The file has no content (using java based config) except a couple of namespaces.

Comment: Did you try a xml validator? Sometimes it can be hard to spot xml syntax errors with the naked eye.

Comment: Looking at errors  / traces again. The EOF exceptions seems to 'jive' with 'premature end of file'. But maybe error actually came from reading a file other than 'servlet-context.xml'. Maybe the error message is misleading. Hold on... I will poke around that stack trace if I see some clues.

Comment: If I were to create a new project then copy the contents to the new project, error seems to go away.

Comment: But it comes back... right? Maybe the thing that nakes the error just hasn't run yet. The problem is still there. Could be something in your workspace metadata corrupted. You can try copying project to a brand-new workspace.

Comment: Source code for the 'EOF' stacktrace suggest the file being read is called 'variablesAndContainers.dat' and is somewhere in the workspace metadata. So this does seem like evidence of workspace metadata corruption.

Comment: Great! I'll change the answer as it seems incorrect now.